# NVIDIA GPU not detected

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

So, I bought new videocard GTX 650 (1gb). Fans are working. Motherboard is msi h61m p31 g3

My pc is

Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-47-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz
Memory: 7.5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 2000

I tried to plug-in VGA cable to videocard and no image (no signal). I tried with HD 2000 - it works. BUT I couldn't find any information about GTX 650 on my pc.
Before all of that I've installed nvidia-driver-470 from apt manager.
After all of that I tried to install from nvidia site and it told me, that I don't have any nvidia gpu.
BIOS settings don't help.
Any questions, commands I need to do?

output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
```

Comment: "BIOS settings don't help" but they must! Please read your user's manual on how to install a discrete GPU card. Typically there's a setting for iGPU/dGPU (PCIe)/Auto.

Comment: i choose PGE instead of IGD, it doesn't work
maybe, problem is broken pcie slot?...

Comment: run lspci in a terminal and if the card does not show up, try another slot.  I did have a GTX640 running on the 435 driver, but changed cards after that.

Comment: I have only one PCIe x16 slot.